# XLOOKUP combined with AutoFill returns #N/A when valid match exists

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've done an xlookup function with lookup values that are strings that average ~400 in length. I ensured that the `lookup_array` and `return_array` have the same number of rows, are in the same position and have anchored the ranges so that they remain constant using the fill down functionality. Here's an example of what my xlookup call would look like:

```
.Range(.Cells(dataRow, nextCol), .Cells(nRows, nextCol)).Formula2 = XLOOKUP(C3,C$3:C$11631, A$3:AB$11631)
```

Once the `auto-fill` is complete, I realize that not all the rows are filled in. Some of them return `#N/A` which signifies that there was no match. However, there is a match. I realized that if I click on the formula bar of an cell that returned `#N/A` and then pressed enter to re-execute the function the correct value is returned.

I'm not entirely sure what is causing this and some insight would be appreciated. As a work around I used a `for` loop to iterate through all the rows and insert the xlookup function individually instead of using `FillDown` to get the desired functionality.

I found a way to reproduce this problem. I created a table with the following contents:

| Name | Long String | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name-1 | QFQ9JES4X2APU8U28RBTIMLOQCR5EKA16Q0JPSW3BPMX6XYLZOLQ8RWC7NY89NSMASUPLKX42D0JYU8KAE4LM87I95WEFOEHNH0R1E450NM3CVVY871JPXPARO6LPDYLDH337NNLZMBSBNIDXFODY4IM181I2YDMRO2SSO0LDO1NOX6KJ80HJOWIMB8PB68ISS24XH76AWOP79ZS2VSIZIBKW74KEQXIH0IIU73XS4DLHCDXNDELQ4VD4KOD7AFRALXNQMJUY6WRAS5D0P41MO4AXSZINDGSYY902IPKKVKQGK5W7EA1YN54M3MDH70VDJSO9C4S3MWZZEKVY7DA386KI5X69UNRAICPD8I568HXC8MPI4U5FNTZ0PT06CTTHG6U8T0WISAFPXR5L286SS934FZF5ZH46P4BZM5PJDH4OE7X4OTJD7REJLOX0BDZ0I1 | data |
| name-2 | QFQ9JES4X2APU8U28RBTIMLOQCR5EKA16Q0JPSW3BPMX6XYLZOLQ8RWC7NY89NSMASUPLKX42D0JYU8KAE4LM87I95WEFOEHNH0R1E450NM3CVVY871JPXPARO6LPDYLDH337NNLZMBSBNIDXFODY4IM181I2YDMRO2SSO0LDO1NOX6KJ80HJOWIMB8PB68ISS24XH76AWOP79ZS2VSIZIBKW74KEQXIH0IIU73XS4DLHCDXNDELQ4VD4KOD7AFRALXNQMJUY6WRAS5D0P41MO4AXSZINDGSYY902IPKKVKQGK5W7EA1YN54M3MDH70VDJSO9C4S3MWZZEKVY7DA386KI5X69UNRAICPD8I568HXC8MPI4U5FNTZ0PT06CTTHG6U8T0WISAFPXR5L286SS934FZF5ZH46P4BZM5PJDH4OE7X4OTJD7REJLOX0BDZ0I2 | data |
| ... | ... | ... |
| name-20000 | QFQ9JES4X2APU8U28RBTIMLOQCR5EKA16Q0JPSW3BPMX6XYLZOLQ8RWC7NY89NSMASUPLKX42D0JYU8KAE4LM87I95WEFOEHNH0R1E450NM3CVVY871JPXPARO6LPDYLDH337NNLZMBSBNIDXFODY4IM181I2YDMRO2SSO0LDO1NOX6KJ80HJOWIMB8PB68ISS24XH76AWOP79ZS2VSIZIBKW74KEQXIH0IIU73XS4DLHCDXNDELQ4VD4KOD7AFRALXNQMJUY6WRAS5D0P41MO4AXSZINDGSYY902IPKKVKQGK5W7EA1YN54M3MDH70VDJSO9C4S3MWZZEKVY7DA386KI5X69UNRAICPD8I568HXC8MPI4U5FNTZ0PT06CTTHG6U8T0WISAFPXR5L286SS934FZF5ZH46P4BZM5PJDH4OE7X4OTJD7REJLOX0BDZ0I20000 | data |

So I took row 1 and `auto-filled` it until row 20000. In column `D` row `1`, I wrote the following formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(B1,B$1:B$20000,A$1:C$20000)
```

Then I `auto-filled` until column D row 20000. I looked back at the results and saw that `#N/A` was coming up for some of the cells.

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(dataRow, nextCol), .Cells(nRows, nextCol)).Formula2 = XLOOKUP(C3,C$3:C$11631, A$3:AB$11631)` No need for filldown.

Comment: Interesting, this does replace having to use `FillDown`. However, the same issue still persists. There are rows filled in with `#N/A` where there should be a valid return value.

Comment: How should this formula work? It's not double-quoted and it doesn't start with an equal sign. The lookup value is the same as the lookup column. Most often, the result and the lookup value are in one, and the lookup and return arrays are in another worksheet. Please elaborate.

Comment: @VBasic2008, I'm confused as what you mean as how the formula is supposed to work. Do you mean how is [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) supposed to work? The `lookup_value` and the `lookup_column` are not the same. The lookup value is a cell value and the lookup column is a range that happens to include the lookup value.

Comment: Have you tried `.Range(.Cells(dataRow, nextCol), .Cells(nRows, nextCol)).Formula = "=XLOOKUP(C3,C$3:C$11631,A$3:AB$11631)"`?

Comment: I have now, and it wasn't working for me. But after reading the [difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/range-formula-vs-formula2) between formula and formula2 it made sense why. I need to use formula2 since I'm using multiple values.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `returning` not `using` multiple values. I've also edited the question to add a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: How wasn't it working for you? Which multiple values are you talking about? You are not sharing enough information. Could you share the explicit destination range address, the address where the result should go (the spill range)? It looks like `... .Formula = "=INDEX(A$3:A$11631,MATCH(C3,C$3:C$11631,0))"` should cover it.